# How to get the nth place of PI using ruby BigMath

Tags: ruby

I am trying to solve a challenge that finds the first 10 digits within pi that are palindromic.  To do this, I wanted to iterate through the index of the digits of pi to see if n = n..n+10 reversed is equal.  How do I go to an nth place of the PI constant in ruby?

Thank you!

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigMath.html#method-i-PI then convert it to a string?

Comment: What is the precision of the inbuilt PI? I don't think it is enough to look for digits that are asked.

Comment: @sawa built in PI is 20 precision e,g. `3.14159265358979323846`

Comment: using BigMath, I can do adjust the precision to as many places as I'd like

Comment: please note `BigMath.PI(n)` comes out as `0.3141592...` instead of `3.141592` and converting it `to_f` returns the same as `Math::PI` with a precision of 20.

Comment: but how do I just present the nth place of pi?

Answer (score 2):

This is one way.

**Code**

```
require "bigdecimal/math"

def find_first(len)
  start = 3
  n = [10,len+start].max
  loop do
    s = BigMath.PI(n).to_s[start..-1]
    s = s[0...s.index('E')]
    a = s.each_char.each_cons(len).with_index.find { |a,i| a == a.reverse }
    return a if a
    start += s.size
    n *= 2
  end
end
```

The index returned (e.g., `23` for `n=>2`) is the offset from the right of the decimal point where the palindrome begins.

To determine `s.index('E')` it would be faster to start at the end of the string and work backward, but I didn't bother doing that.

**Examples**

```
(2..10).each { |i| print "#{i}: "; p find_first(i) }
[["3", "3"], 23] 
[["1", "4", "1"], 0]
[["7", "7", "7", "7"], 2]
[["4", "6", "2", "6", "4"], 18]
[["9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9"], 88]
[["1", "7", "3", "6", "3", "7", "1"], 285]
[["2", "3", "9", "1", "1", "9", "3", "2"], 878]
[["3", "9", "8", "9", "8", "9", "8", "9", "3"], 398]
[["0", "1", "3", "6", "7", "7", "6", "3", "1", "0"], 2714]
```

It would be nice if [BigMath.PI](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigMath.html#method-i-PI) could be used lazily, but that does not seem to be the case.

Comment: this is pretty impressive.  I wish I could have thought of this intuitively, but I'm still green!  Much to learn, thanks!